# how to retrieve certificates in VSTS-build if agent is running as "network service"

Tags: azure-devops, manifest, code-signing

in the past, we used VSTS build agents, running with domain accounts on on-prem build machines. In such scenario, certificates could be stored into the domain accounts personal store (manually, by logging in once with this account). So a later build could get the certificates by thumbprint for signing e.g. a manifest.

Now, the agents run with "Network Service", because we no longer have a local domain (all moved to Azure AD). All works, except the retrieval of certificates from the store. I already used the mmc snap-in to connect to the service (VSTSAgent), and installed certificates to this personal store, but still the build fails with "Error MSB3323: Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store.".

If I log-on to the machine and run from within VS, all works well, but of course here I am using a different account (with a different personal store), but this at least tells me that solution & projects are fine. And the pipelines are OK as well, because they still work OK on the "old" build-machines that use a domain account.

So, if anyone has an idea or can point me to some information on how to use the VSTSAgent running as "Network Service" together with signing (from the certificate store), that highly appreciated.
Many thanks, Sebastian